# If A = QR is a decomposition of an upper Hessenberg square matrix using Givens rotations, then Q is upper hessenberg.

Tags: linear-algebra

If A = QR is a decomposition of an upper Hessenberg square matrix using Givens rotations, then Q is upper hessenberg.

How can we proceed to prove?

Comment: Do you know how $Q$ is formed based on Givens rotations?

Comment: Unfourtanly, it isn't specified.